# Mapping hostnames in --hosts (-s) to addresses

Tags: virtual-machine, linux-mint, vertica

Guest: Virtual Box (Linux Mint with 2 network adapters)

When I try to create Vercita's db like this:

```
echo "NETWORKING=yes" >> /etc/sysconfig/network
export SHORT_HOSTNAME=$(hostname -s)
expect install_image/vertica.expect
```

I get error:

```
Mapping hostnames in --hosts (-s) to addresses...
    hplaptop resolved to multiple (2) addresses: (IPv4...) 10.0.2.15, 192.11.12.102 (IPv6...) <none>
    Error: Unable to resolve 'hplaptop'
Installation FAILED with errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```bash
echo "NETWORKING=yes" >> /etc/sysconfig/network
export SHORT_HOSTNAME=10.0.2.15 # I assume this is the internal IP add
expect install_image/vertica.expect
```

If one hostname resolves to two IP addresses, you'd have to expect that behaviour. And IP addresses in a Vertica cluster config are less complicated to work with than DNS names or host names ...